# Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality for weighted Sobolev space with exponential weights

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Consider the weighted $L^p_\omega(\mathbb{R}^d)$ space on $\mathbb{R}^d$ be the set of Lebesgue measurable functions such that 
$$\|f\|_{L^p_\omega}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f|^p\omega_\mu(x)\,dx< \infty,$$ where $\omega_\mu(x)=\exp(-\mu |x|^2)$ or $\omega_\mu(x)=\exp(-\mu\sqrt{1+|x|^2})$ for some $\mu>0$. Consider the weighted sobolev space $W^{1,p}_\omega(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that 
$$W^{1,p}_\omega(\mathbb{R}^d)=\{u\in L^p_\omega\mid  \partial_{x_i}u\in L^p_\omega,\, i=1,\ldots, d \},$$
where $\partial_{x_i}$ denotes the weak derivative in the distribution sense. Similarly we define the high-order sobolev space $W^{2,p}_\omega(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that 
$\partial_{x_ix_j}u\in L^p_\omega$ for all $i,j$.

I was wondering whether the [Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem)  for the classical Sobolev space still holds? In particular, whether for $1\le p<n$, we have 
$$
\|u\|_{L^{p^*}_\omega(\mathbf{R}^n)}\leq C \|Du\|_{L^{p}_\omega(\mathbf{R}^n)}.$$

with $1/p* = 1/p - 1/n$? Do you have a reference for this?

---

The main motivation is that I would like to find some weighted spaces on $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $L^p_\omega(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^q_\omega(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $q\ge p>1$, and then study the elliptic equation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, say 
$$
-\partial_i a^{ij}(x)\partial_j u+ru=f(x), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^d,
$$
where $a^{ij}$ is strictly elliptic. That is why I introduce this decaying weight, such that $\omega (x)dx$ is a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The exponential weight is introduced to involve bounded functions or functions with polynomial growth at infinity.

Comment: I don't think so. At least for $p=2$, the GNS inequality implies that the associated  semigroup is ultracontractive, i.e. maps $L^1$ into $L^\infty$. This is definitively not the case for your first choice of measure (and I'm pretty sure that it's also not true for the second).

Comment: In general, if you want such an inequality, you need a notion of dimension (for $p^\ast$) that is adapted to your choice of measure. Take a look at the book by Bakry, Gentil and Ledoux for example.

Comment: @MaoWao Is it easy to see that the semigroup is not ultracontractive? Are there some general techniques to see something like that?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The easiest way to see this is probably the following: Eigenfunctions of the generator are just scaled under the action of the semigroup, so they should be bounded if the semigroup were ultracontractive. But for the first choice of measure the eigenfunctions are (scaled versions of) the Hermite polynomials, most of which are not bounded.

Comment: In general, I am more familiar with sufficient criteria than necessary criteria for ultracontractivity. In general, the GNS inequality the OP asks for is probably one of the best ways to check.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your comment. I was trying to see whether I could go the other way round. I suspect that for my weight the GNS inequality does not hold.

Comment: @MaoWao I am sorry to bother you again. You said that the Hermite polynomials are the eigenfunctions of the generator. But wouldn't the generator in question by given by the Laplacian? Probably I am missing the point.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Not bothering at all, I like to think about these things. To answer your question: The generator is $\nabla_\mu^\ast \nabla$, where $\nabla_\mu^\ast$ is the adjoint of the gradient viewed as an (unbounded) operator from $L^2(\mathbb R^d,\mu)$ to $L^2(\mathbb R^d,\mu)^d$. If you compute this in the usual way via integration by parts, you will see that in addition to the divergence you pick up a summand that comes from the derivative of the weight $\omega$.

Comment: To be concrete, for the first choice of the weight, the generator is (up to some scaling I am too lazy to figure out) $-\Delta +x\cdot \nabla$.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you. I forgot to take the measure into account when I did the integration by parts (after years of just dealing with the Lebesgue measure it became a habit). Now everything makes much more sense.